# Free() crashes program

Tags: c, free

When calling a function `b_destroy`, the program crashes before it reaches the end of the function. The function looks like this:

```
void b_destroy(Buffer * const pBD){
#ifdef DEBUG
printf("IN DESTROY\n");
printf("BUFFER ADDRESS %d\n",pBD);
printf("HEAD ADDRESS %d\n",pBD->ca_head);
#endif
if(pBD != NULL || pBD->ca_head != NULL){
    if (pBD->ca_head != NULL)
        free(pBD->ca_head);
    if (pBD != NULL)
        free(pBD);
}
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("EXITING DESTROY\n");
#endif
}
```

I know the pointers aren't `NULL` because I'm able to print out the memory location. Any ideas why it crashes?

Comment: If you need any more info let me know

Comment: Just because a pointer is non-null doesn't mean it's valid.

Comment: Your logic is wrong in there. Think about what happens if `pBD` is indeed null.

Comment: Calling `free` doesn't set the pointer to NULL so the memory that the pointers are pointing to might have already been freed.

Comment: only place I'm calling free is from this function, and it only gets called once.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem...A function I called before reallocated memory to a temp buffer and I forgot to assign is to the main buffer -.-

Comment: Can you post the code where this memory is allocated?

Comment: Just a note, if you happen to be on unix/linux [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) is insanely good at showing you where these sorts of errors are.

Comment: I'll try that. Program works when I read in small text files. When larger text files are read, it calls `realloc` (which is working), but crashes at destroy.

Answer (score 2):

When you free some pointer you should always set the pointer to NULL immediately. If you don't they might lead to crash else where in the program. That might be the case in your program. Also always print addresses using %x (for memory addresses) format specifier and not %d (for signed integers)

Need to look at your complete program to find the problem. Try setting pointer to NULL after freeing at all places that might fix your problem.

Comment: Well the driver code that calls this function sets the pointer to NULL after it's called.

Comment: Agree about `setting pointer to NULL after freeing at all places`.  Note: OP function will not allow that here for some questionable reason `pBD`  is `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Think carefully about your logic here:

```
if(pBD != NULL || pBD->ca_head != NULL)
```

If pBD is 0, then your logic is:

```
if(0 || 0->ca_head != NULL) { // that 0-> will seg fault

}
```

Maybe you want something like:

```
if (pBD && pBD->ca_head)
    free(pBD->ca_head);
if (pBD)
    free(pBD);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that the address is not null, but rather that the data there has not already been freed. You need to search elsewhere to see if the same memory has already been freed, as Free doesn't set the given pointer to null afterwords.